# What is the order of actions of join?

Tags: sql, join

Imagine I have sql query like this

```
select * from table1 
         join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col2
         join table3 on table2.col3 = table3.col3
```

What is the order of `join` actions? Does it firstly creates cartesian product of all involved tables and then performs filtering on `join` conditions? Or it goes consequently, creating result table from joining `table1` and `table2`, and then joining `table3` to that result?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server then the Query Plan will tell you how compiler has decided to actually execute your query. If you're using something else, then maybe that has something similar.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough, so you mean that there is no rules on how `join` is performed and it may depend on certain query?

Comment: I would take a guess an say it depends on how the database engine implements an inner join operation. Are indexes and/or primary keys involved? Is this for SQL Server, MySQL, or another RDBMS? Can you view the execution plan (or `EXPLAIN`)? Does the execution plan change if you join on other columns or select specific ones from a particular table?

Comment: Ideally you don't care how it's executed; SQL is a _declarative_ language in which you describe what you want and the compiler takes care of the rest. You may need to investigate what is actually happening, for example because you are experiencing long running times, to check that you have indexed your tables appropriately, and even to add query hints about how to use indices, but this is unusual.

Comment: Logically, from left to right. But in practice it can be any order - the optimizer tries to find the cheapest/fastest way to produce the result.

Comment: The point of the question was to compare speed and memory consumption of `join` and `where`. My opinion was that cross joining all of the tables and then filtering by `where` conditions would be much slower and memory consuming then proper inner joining, because I thought that it is filtered step by step so far less rows are stored and evaluated in that process. Is it so in reality?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to compare explicit JOIN and implicit, comma separated joins? Don't bother, same performance.

Comment: @Nourless SQL is a declarative language. The engine is free to run the query in any form it wishes to as long as it produces the result you want. You can get the execution plan for the query using `EXPLAIN` and to see what the engine would do as of this precise moment. The plan can change at any time without notice.